# How can I integrate an value with Payfort specific verify OTP in swift?

Tags: swift, payfort

This is my function for verifying an OTP specific Payfort with value, but display (invalid value OTP), but in response in postman request display (success OTP) why this execute, and the problem in the OTP value must be alphanumeric, so how can I define an alphanumeric parameter?

```
func verifyOTP(getTotal: String, getRandom: String,getTransaction: String) {
    let signatureStructure = "sportEyeByAbouElgoukhaccess_code=hRRVGXrIpHSYoH19Ebwtamount=\(getTotal)currency=EGPlanguage=enmerchant_identifier=e54638ebmerchant_order_id=\(getRandom)merchant_reference=\(getRandom)otp=\(123456)payment_option=VALUphone_number=01008606003service_command=OTP_VERIFYtotal_downpayment=0sportEyeByAbouElgoukh"
    let base64Str = signatureStructure.sha256()
    let parameters = ["otp":123456,"currency":"EGP","merchant_order_id":getRandom,"signature":base64Str,"merchant_reference":getRandom,"payment_option":"VALU","merchant_identifier":"e54638eb","amount":getTotal,"access_code":"hRRVGXrIpHSYoH19Ebwt","total_downpayment":"0","service_command":"OTP_VERIFY","phone_number":"01008606003","language":"en"] as [String : Any]
    Alamofire.request(URLAPi.URL_Payment_Api , method : .post , parameters : parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default ).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let jsonpayfortrequest : JSON  = JSON(response.result.value!)
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
        else {
            print("error connection")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Joakim Danielson, i deal with payfort  so payfort integrate with valu you understand me !! , i have document from payfort to integrate valu payment from payfort  .

Comment: Joakim Danielson, i do that , & removed some old my accounts , and this is my real account on stack-overflow, about my question how define alphanumeric parameter ?

Comment: I am already make request to delete all old accounts , and wait for this request to remove  but still now old accounts not remove .

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible. Can you fix it?